# Assignment with a guard

Tags: javascript

I wish to have a guard for the following:

```
filteredStatus = status.filter(v=>v.getIn(['user','id']) == 2)
```

in case status is undefined. If status if undefined I wish for filteredStatus to be undefined or perhaps something else if thats best practice.

Later in my code I will show a spinner if filteredStatus is undefined otherwise I will display a table.

This is what I do at the moment:

```
filteredStatus = status?status.filter(v=>v.getIn(['user','id']) == 2):undefined
```

Comment: _"perhaps something else if thats best practice"_ There's no best practice here - what you set it to should be defined by your requirements.

Comment: Why not just do `if (status) filteredStatus = status.filter(…)`? Or `if (status !== undefined)` or `if (Array.isArray(status))`

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, you can do this

```
filteredStatus = status && status.filter(v=>v.getIn(['user','id']) == 2)
```

But ternary works too.